# What is the origin of viruses? How could they get both living and non-living characteristics?

Tags: evolution, virology

I read that viruses are called intermediate between living and non-living particles. Well, if so, then where did they originate from?  From living or non-living? If they originated from either living or non-living then how could they have both the characteristics of living and non-living?

Comment: [Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/why-isnt-a-virus-alive/9445#9445) is a somehow similar post that might interest you. But it does not answer the interesting question of their origin.