# What are the characteristics of a living organism?

Tags: life, definitions, philosophy-of-science

It seemed fairly basic at first, and yet I have to ask because even a quick Google search reveals that it doesn't seem to be quite so straight-forward anymore. After more research, I found multiple lists, some with six points, others seven or eight. Some lists shared six points and only differed on one, but others had five different points and divided and named the points differently such as Respiration vs Metabolism, Adapt vs Evolve, Homeostasis vs simply consisting of cells, etc.

Maybe it never really was simple, but when I learned basic middle school life science in the 1990s I seem to remember a clear and concise list of 7-8 distinct terms. I know they were just the summary given by the author of whatever textbook we used, but I remember several sources having similar lists (cannot say for sure if they were exactly the same), including a textbook, an educational video game, and a poster.

I'm also told that this has become a bit of a debate in the biology community, whether such a black and white distinction of "living" or "not living" is prudent. Questions such as [this one on viruses](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/why-isnt-a-virus-alive) are an example of how it is difficult to categorize life. However, I noted in my research that there was still clearly overlap in meaning of definitions, it was just in description and division of points that they differed. This suggests to me there is still a generally agreed upon core definition that is simply described by different people, specifically authors, with a few areas of possible debate.

- **What are the current generally agreed upon characteristics, the common denominators?** (They all reproduce?)
- **What characteristics are commonly debated** and therefore would unwarranted to claim? (Specifying cell structure?)

With the understanding that an answer will require an objective synthesis of a range of content and opinions, debate on what should or should not be characteristics is discouraged. Rather, an impassioned summary of the [current  scientific consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_consensus) on this question is what I am looking for.

It seems to me that even if this is a topic of opinionated debate, it is certainly at the core of Biology and would be worthwhile to be addressed in an academic manner, be accessible, and available to reference on this site.

(PS - Not in any way a homework question, never was, just a curious 30-year father. Unless you are counting questions I have to answer from a curious little boy.)

Comment: [I asked a related question.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/why-isnt-a-virus-alive) "Does it have it's own ribosomes?" is a good objective classification, but why should anyone care? Ultimately any answer is subjective.

Comment: The definition of any subject is open to subjectivity. Asking "What is maths?", "What is programming?", "What is beginners English?" or "What is religion?" in the respective SEs would all be equally be off topic. Additionally, I think the attitude of approaching a new community expecting their answers and then insulting the community is particularly unpleasant.

Comment: @James I agree...if that is what I had asked. But I am asking "What are agreed upon characteristics?" This can be done objectively by simply reviewing  all the subjective definitions and summarizing what they agree upon. As you say, everything is subjective at some point, so that is why scientists have peer reviews and such, so by the use of consensus of experts we can arrive at a conclusion that can be labeled objectively correct. And I still believe that voting to close a question with no comment as to why, when it is not obvious, is far more insulting than anything you think I've said.

Comment: @James if I am simply not communicating it well I will try to make an edit this evening. But it is a bit difficult to know what to correct with no constructive feedback (besides your own recent comment which did help) so if you or anyone else thinks they can see where I'm going wrong here I'm still just not sure, even after an edit, that it won't be closed again for some unknown reason. Maybe I've expressed my frustration poorly, but can you see that the attitude of approaching a new member of a community and expecting them to know what's wrong without telling them is equally unpleasant?

Comment: I didn't mean to say *everything* is subjective. There are empirical evidences. The issue comes when trying to devise a test to answer "what is living?" Many philosophers have moved away from the living/non-living divide & prefer something a little more nuanced. You've unwittingly stumbled into an age-old, unoriginal, unanswerable question. Here, we like questions that are answerable & want to avoid questions that induce debates. Because of this I'm not sure if any amount of edits will help. Recently in the chat we even considered closing that virus question for the same reasons.

Comment: @James I hope with my edit you can see that an answer to this can be even more objective and less contentious than your own on viruses. I'm simply looking for summary and synthesis of material. Not conjecture. Trust me, from my time at [Christianity.SE](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth) I've learned the fine line between a "truth" question and a verifiable summary.

Comment: In meta we're struggling with hwk questions and how to deal with poorly researched/trivial questions & there is some over-zealous closing in the meanwhile. Personally I closed the question because it is too subjective to be answered with empirical biology. [A similar question was closed on Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21207/definition-of-and-difference-between-living-and-non-living/21220#21220). They said there was no line & the division came down to semantics. It's very unsatisfying.

Comment: If you want a practical answer, you can just ask: Is this thing in the [tree of life](https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/opentree/argus/opentree5.0@ott93302)?

Comment: @joshua if you read the help pages and meta regarding homework closure you will understand that it was closed not because we literally thought it was your homework

Comment: @rg255 Yes, I realize this. I did read it. (Which is why I make light of it mentioning my boy...) And its why I detailed my prior research better in this edit. I considered giving a few sample lists, but...well research it with "characteristics of living organism" Google search and you'll see what I'm talking about. Me quoting multiple lists in the question isn't going to benefit anyone who is actually attempting to answer the question.

Comment: I don't think bio.se is the place for this question. However, I'd thoroughly recommend [Koshland's 2002 Science article "The Seven Pillars of Life"](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/295/5563/2215.full). It has excellent detail & justification for what "life" is. `P(rogram), I(mprovisation), C(ompartmentalization), E(nergy), R(egeneration), A(daptability), S(eclusion), PICERAS, for short—are the fundamental principles on which a living system is based.`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to note that there is no such thing as a scientific, objective definition of life, and that many scientists disagree on a given definition, and that every definition has it's limits.

[However, the one from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life#Definitions)

> Since there is no unequivocal definition of life, most current definitions in biology are descriptive. Life is considered a characteristic of something that exhibits all or most of the following traits:[10][12][13][14][15][16][17]
>
> **Homeostasis**: regulation of the internal environment to maintain a constant state; for example, sweating to reduce temperature
>
> **Organization**: being structurally composed of one or more cells — the basic units of life
>
> **Metabolism**: transformation of energy by converting chemicals and energy into cellular components (anabolism) and decomposing organic matter (catabolism). Living things require energy to maintain internal organization (homeostasis) and to produce the other phenomena associated with life.
>
> **Growth**: maintenance of a higher rate of anabolism than catabolism. A growing organism increases in size in all of its parts, rather than simply accumulating matter.
>
> **Adaptation**: the ability to change over time in response to the environment. This ability is fundamental to the process of evolution and is determined by the organism's heredity, diet, and external factors.
>
> **Response to stimuli**: a response can take many forms, from the contraction of a unicellular organism to external chemicals, to complex reactions involving all the senses of multicellular organisms. A response is often expressed by motion; for example, the leaves of a plant turning toward the sun (phototropism), and chemotaxis.
>
> **Reproduction**: the ability to produce new individual organisms, either asexually from a single parent organism, or sexually from two parent organisms.

[Encyclopedia Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/topic/life)

> - Metabolism
> - Respiration
> - Sensitivity (responding to stimuli like gravity and sunlight)
> - Nutrition
> - Excretion (getting rid of CO2)
> - Growth
> - Reproduction
> - Homeostasis

Comment: "you have to note that there is no such thing"... Part of this question is about dealing with just that. Generally agreed upon. Consensus. But you dismissed it and just gave me the results of a Google search (which I've already done). Was hoping for more. The latter encyclopedia version is what seems to me to have been a pretty standardized answer in the 90s. It was in textbooks, educational video games, etc. So if there was consensus then, why not anymore?

Comment: @Joshua "textbooks" are not consensus. They are the opinions of the publisher. Anybody can write one, and if it's cheap enough schools will buy them. Textbook authors generally take the viewpoint that younger readers can't handle ambiguity, and so create facts where none actually exist. I'm willing to bet if you traveled back to your childhood, all the media you mentioned didn't completely agree.

Comment: @MattDMo if you combined that with a summary of what various definitions do agree on and what they don't, you'd have a winning answer.

Comment: Just wanted to alert you that the question has been edited considerably. I believe its still the core question I intended, but hopefully I'm more clear this time. Thanks.