# Which biological kingdom comprises the greatest biomass on Earth?

Tags: ecology, life

Which of the five biological kingdoms - animalia, protista, plantera, monera, or fungi - has the largest biomass?

To clarify, if the biomass of every species in each of these kingdoms was added up, which kingdom would have the greatest sum?

Comment: A really clear, well defined question with great biological significance. In a silly way, this number can help us quantify which is "winning"! Welcome to Bio.SE!

Comment: Please note that the 5 kingdoms you list are NOT monophyletic groups.

Answer (score 4):

**Probably Eukaryotes. Specifically, plants.**

This is a very fundamental question of life that is often overlooked. It goes without saying that plants and animals are the strongest contenders. However [bacteria may also rival them](http://www.pnas.org/cgi/reprint/95/12/6578.pdf). Be aware though that this is a contentious claim given more [thorough estimations that take into account fluctuations in bacterial presence](http://www.pnas.org/content/109/40/16213.full). [This EMBO Reports *science and society* article](http://embor.embopress.org/content/13/9/772.1) claims that plants account for 99% of Eukaryotic biomass.

For further reading the [Wikipedia page on biomass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomass_(ecology)) doesn't seem too shabby for more details on tonnage and methods of calculation.

---

The most *numerous organisms* could possibly be [viruses](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/guess-what-the-most-abundant-organism-on-earth-is-19254662/?no-ist) or [bacteriophages](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap080421.html) depending on [if you count viruses as "living"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/why-isnt-a-virus-alive).