# Is a spore 'alive'?

Tags: cell-biology

Referencing this article: [What are spores?](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-are-spores-definition-types-quiz.html)

'A spore is typically a ***single cell*** surrounded by a thick cell wall for protection.'

So a spore is a 'cell'? This implies that a spore is a living thing; and not just a means to a living thing.

If this is the case, where does the spore get its energy? Oxygen, water, etc.?  Is there a name for the mechanism with which a spore extracts/obtains energy?

So many questions!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is based upon the definition of life and there is no such definition in biology. Ultimately, the definition of life is a matter of philosophy, not biology. Also, the post contains several question which make it too broad.

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE! Feel free to take a [tour] of this site. I appreciate your curiosity and eagerness to learn, but please limit yourself to one question per post. This is enforced to make sure answers are not too long. You may however ask multiple questions for different aspects though :)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why isn't a virus “alive”?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/why-isnt-a-virus-alive)

Comment: Spores generally do not need energy; the cell's metabolic activity is suspended indefinitely [a technical source](http://jb.asm.org/content/197/5/992.full).

Comment: Thanks all. Wasn't looking to start trouble. 'Alive' was the wrong word to use I imagine. Basically does it require energy since it is classified in some circles as a 'cell'? mgkrebbs touched on what I was trying to get at.